# storing data from a file into an array

Tags: c++, arrays, file

I have written the following code to read data in columns from a file (area.inp) to an array.  When showing the data in the screen, the first "for" loop shows correct numbers (so the code reads the numbers from the file correctly) but the second "for" loop shows incorrect set of numbers. I cannot get my head around the problem.  I would appreciate any guidance on the problem.

area.inp

```
001.000    003.000
002.000    004.000
006.000    005.000
004.000    002.000
002.000    001.000
```

code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>


using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int j=0;
    double X[j];
    double Y[j];
    static double *p;
    double *q;
    p=X;
    q=Y;


//**** Counting the number of lines

    ifstream myfile("area.inp");
    myfile.unsetf(ios_base::skipws);

    int points = count(
        istream_iterator<char>(myfile),
        istream_iterator<char>(),
        '\n');

    cout << "Number of data in file: " << points << "\n";

//****  Open data file and result
    cout <<"file is open"<< endl;
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("area.inp", ios::in);


    cout <<"Reading data from file"<< endl; 
    for (j=0; j<points; j++)
        {
            cout << std::setprecision(3) << std::fixed;;

            infile >> X[j] >> Y[j];

            cout << "Value of X["<<j<<"]: " << X[j] << endl;

            cout << "Value of Y["<<j<<"]: " << Y[j] << endl;
        }

    cout <<"Showing numbers stored in array"<< endl;


            for (j=0; j<points; j++)
            {

                cout << "Value of X["<<j<<"]: " << X[j] << endl;

                cout << "Value of Y["<<j<<"]: " << Y[j] << endl;
            }

    infile.close();

    return 0;
}

Number of data in file: 5
file is open
Reading data from file
Value of X[0]: 1.000
Value of Y[0]: 3.000
Value of X[1]: 2.000
Value of Y[1]: 4.000
Value of X[2]: 6.000
Value of Y[2]: 5.000
Value of X[3]: 4.000
Value of Y[3]: 2.000
Value of X[4]: 2.000
Value of Y[4]: 2.000
Showing numbers stored in array
Value of X[0]: 5.000
Value of Y[0]: 3.000
Value of X[1]: 2.000
Value of Y[1]: 4.000
Value of X[2]: 4.000
Value of Y[2]: 5.000
Value of X[3]: 4.000
Value of Y[3]: 2.000
Value of X[4]: 2.000
Value of Y[4]: 2.000


------------------
(program exited with code: 0)
Press return to continue
```

Comment: Look at `int j=0; double X[j];`.  How many elements can `X` store?

Comment: Besides the fact that `double X[j];` is not standard C++ when `j` is not a constant expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you are creating a 0-length array. To do things your way, you have to allocate the arrays with `new` **after** you've counted the number of points in the file:

```
double *X = new double[points];
double *Y = new double[points];
```

And then at the end of the program, free the memory with `delete`.

I would recommend you avoid arrays and instead use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). In the example, I use [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) to store the points, but you can change that.

```
// Using a vector of pairs
std::vector<std::pair<double, double>> data;

ifstream infile;
infile.open("area.inp");
// You should check here to make sure the file opened ok

// Read the file. No need to know size ahead of time
std::pair<double, double> tmp;
while (infile >> tmp.first >> tmp.second) {
    data.push_back(tmp);
}

// Print the results
std::cout << "Number of pairs: " << data.size() << std::endl;
for (auto p : data) {
    std::cout << p.first << ", " << p.second << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'r array X[] and Y[] are of zero size.
Curious why there was no seg fault

Try changing as below,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>


using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int j=0;
static double *p;
double *q;


//**** Counting the number of lines

ifstream myfile("area.inp");
myfile.unsetf(ios_base::skipws);

const int points = count(
    istream_iterator<char>(myfile),
    istream_iterator<char>(),
    '\n');

double X[points];
double Y[points];
p=X;
q=Y;

cout << "Number of data in file: " << points << "\n";

//****  Open data file and result
cout <<"file is open"<< endl;
ifstream infile;
infile.open("area.inp", ios::in);


cout <<"Reading data from file"<< endl; 
for (j=0; j<points; j++)
    {
        cout << std::setprecision(3) << std::fixed;;

        infile >> X[j] >> Y[j];

        cout << "Value of X["<<j<<"]: " << X[j] << endl;

        cout << "Value of Y["<<j<<"]: " << Y[j] << endl;
    }

cout <<"Showing numbers stored in array"<< endl;


        for (j=0; j<points; j++)
        {

            cout << "Value of X["<<j<<"]: " << X[j] << endl;

            cout << "Value of Y["<<j<<"]: " << Y[j] << endl;
        }

infile.close();

return 0;
}
```